# Check if a URL's mimetype is not a web page

Tags: java, android

I want to check if a URL's mimetype is not a webpage.  Can I do this in Java? I want to check if the file is a rar or mp3 or mp4 or mpeg or whatever, just not a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

content-type:text/html represents webpage.

Answer (score 3):

You can issue an [`HTTP HEAD`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.4) request and check for `Content-Type` response headers.  You can use the [`HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) before you issue the request.  Then issue the request with [`URLConnection.connect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) and then use [`URLConnection.getContentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) which reads the HTTP headers.

The bonus of using a `HEAD` request is that the actual resource is never transmitted/generated.  You can also use a `GET` request and inspect the resulting stream using [`URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) which will inspect the actual bytes and try to guess what the stream represents.  I think that it looks for [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) or other patterns in the stream.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherent in a URL which will tell you what you will receive when you request it. You have to actually request the resource, and then inspect the `content-type` header. At that point, it's still not clear what you should do - some content types will (almost) always be handled by the browser, e.g. `text/html`. Some types *should* be handled by a browser, e.g. `application/xhtml+xml`. Some types *may* be handled by the browser, e.g. `application/pdf`.

Which, if any, of these you consider to be "webpage" is still not clear - you'll need to decide for yourself.

You can inspect the `content-type` header once you're requested the resource, using, for example, the [`HttpURLConnection` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).